# Storing Results from multiple loops and creating a data frame looking object in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops

**i used for loops :**

```
for i=1:length(thetas)
    theta = thetas(i); % Utility function
    for j=1:length(rhos)
        rho = rhos(j);
        for ii=1:length(gammas)
            gamma = gammas(ii);
            [kss]=equilibirum(debt)wherein      
        end
    end
end
```

**where in each step I essentially change some parameter values to get different values for the column vector `kss` (size: 10000x1)**

e.g the vector of parameters I am looping over are:

```
thetas = [1, 1.5]; 
rhos   = [0, 0.99, 2]; 
gammas = [-1,0,0.76, 0.9, 1] ;
```

**I  want to remember (or store) for which combination of parameters i get the values for `kss'**.

How can I do this Matlab in some easy to understand and easy to export (e.g. in Excel) way? An ideal solution, will make my result look like a data frame object as in python(pandas) or R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html?s_tid=doc_ta) in MATLAB to describe what you wish to accomplish.

```
kss_table = table;
counter = 1;
for i=1:length(thetas)
    theta = thetas(i); % Utility function
    for j=1:length(rhos)
        rho = rhos(j);
        for ii=1:length(gammas)
            gamma = gammas(ii);
            kss = equilibirum(debt)wherein
            kss_table.Theta(counter) = theta;
            kss_table.Rho(counter) = rho;
            kss_table.Gamma(counter) = gamma;
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
    end
end
```